# Find more one newlines in code with egrep?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

How to find more than one newline in code before `}` with regular expression and add warning to it? This is what I tried add bash script in xcode:

```
TAGS2="\}/\n"
echo "searching ${SRCROOT} for ${TAGS2}"
find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" \) -print0 | xargs -0
egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching "($TAGS2).*\$" |
perl -p -e "s/($TAGS2)/ warning\$1/"
```

Comment: If the first one works, why is it in your question? And what is the second one supposed to do? There is no `}` that I can see in any pattern, so I'm not sure how the question is related to the code.

Comment: Can you include an input and expected output?

Comment: @RichardSt-Cyr i want find more than 1 newlines in my code and highlight them.

Comment: `find more than one newline in code before ` - Find: `(?:\r?\n[^}\r\n]*){2}\K(?=\})` replace: `warning` or Find: `((?:\r?\n[^}\r\n]*){2})(?=\})` replace: `$1warning` To find more than 2, change the quantifier to `{2,}`

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you would like to find places in your file where there is a blank line before a line whose first non-blank character is a <kbd>}</kbd>, the following `awk` program might help.

```
awk '/\S/              { blanks = NR - prev - 1; prev = NR }
     blanks && /^\s*}/ { printf "%d: WARNING: Useless blank line\n", NR - 1 }'
```

That will work with Gnu awk; with more Posix-compatible awks you'll need to use `/[^ \t]/` and `/^[ \t]*}/` (or something similar) to instead of the given patterns.

`egrep` is a wonderful tool but it does line-by-line matching. It cannot recognize multiline patterns, nor can you change the line delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

egrep does not work with multiple lines.
You can use *sed* (or awk as mentioned in previous answer) instead of "egrep". No need to use perl. See the script below.

```
TAGS2="}"
echo "searching ${SRCROOT} for ${TAGS2}"
find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" \) \
  -print -exec sed "/$TAGS2/{ # search for tag 
    =; # print line number
    N; # join with next line
    s/$TAGS2/warning/; # substitute tags found with warning
  }" {} \;
```